# variable is not found inside ajax

Tags: ajax

```
                <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="email" class="col-form-label">Email address:</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="signUpEmail" name="email">
        </div>
            <div class="form-group">
        <label for="pwd" class="col-form-label">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="signUpPassword" name="password" onchange="check_pass()">
                                         </div>  
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <label for="pwd" class="col-form-label">Confirm Password:</label>
                                                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="signUpConPassword" name="password" onchange="check_pass()">
                                                </div>
                                            </form>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="modal-footer">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="signUpSubmit" disabled="true" >Sign Up</button>

                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            function check_pass() 
            {
                //alert(document.getElementById('signUpPassword').value);
            if (document.getElementById('signUpPassword').value ==
                    document.getElementById('signUpConPassword').value) {
                document.getElementById('signUpSubmit').disabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                document.getElementById('signUpSubmit').disabled = true;
            }
        }
        $('#signUpSubmit').click(function() 
        {
            //alert("signup completed");
            var email=document.getElementById('signUpEmail');
            var password = document.getElementById('signUpPassword');
            $.ajax({
                url: 'signup.php',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    email: $email,
                    password: $password
                },
                success: function() {
                    alert('Email Sent');
                }               
            });
        });
        </script>
```

This code snippet shows `ReferenceError: $email is not defined` when I click on the `signupSubmit` button although I defined the variable inside the function.
I also try

```
var email=document.getElementById('signUpEmail').value;
var password = document.getElementById('signUpPassword').value;
```

but, same error. I guess there is a problem in variable declaration. What is the correct form of variable declaration inside the function?

Comment: Why did you put a `$` before the variable names?

Comment: @Musa ! my roommate name is Musa. Do you say `email: email,` ?

Comment: Yes, also use the `document.getElementById('signUpEmail').value` version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the $email and $password to email ,password

```
$.ajax({
                    url: 'signup.php',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        email: email,
                        password: password
                    },
                    success: function() {
                        alert('Email Sent');
                    }               
                });
```

Comment: please do not add more than one answer for the same question!

Answer (score 1):

Remove the **$**

```
data: {
            email: $email,
            password: $password
        },
```

The data being passed has two properties - "email" and "password", the values of the properties are stored in the variables *email* and *password*.

Your code should look like this:

```
/* Remove these two lines */
var email=document.getElementById('signUpEmail');
var password = document.getElementById('signUpPassword');

...

data: {
    "email": $("#signUpEmail").val(),
    "password": $("#signUpPassword").val()
}
```

The **$** is the jQuery function call, and the "#signUpEmail" is the selector for the element with an id of "signUpEmail".  The **val()** method will return the value of the input.

```
document.getElementById("something").value
```

is the same as

```
$("#something").val()
```

If you're using jQuery for the Ajax, you might as well use it to get the values.

Comment: There may a syntax error in `"email": $("#signUpEmail").val(),
    "password": $("#signUpPassword").val();`

Comment: @moyen - Thank you, fixed